# Struggling to Make magento to work

Tags: magento2

Hello i trying to make magento to work on my laptop. first problem i ran into was black screen but where able to fix it. My next problem is infinite loading after admin login on the backend. [image]

I already increased te Memory_limit in php.ini to 2048M it was 512M. Already cleared browser caches. Currently using xampp 7.3.13 and Magento 2.3.3.

Would apreciate it alot if someone can help me.

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: @YasirLatif thank you i forgot to check the console. with the console i finally found the solution online. Had to replace 'symlink' to 'copy' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magegento\app\etc\di.xml <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>

Comment: I’m happy it helps

Comment: check system requirement and your Magento version too.